# How to Access Fields of Custom Data Types without Record Syntax in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, field

I'd like to understand how to access fields of custom data types without using the record syntax. In LYAH it is proposed to do it like this:

```
-- Example
data Person = Subject String String Int Float String String deriving (Show)  

guy = Subject "Buddy" "Finklestein" 43 184.2 "526-2928" "Chocolate"  

firstName :: Person -> String  
firstName (Subject firstname _ _ _ _ _) = firstname
```

I tried applying this way of accessing data by getting the value of a node of a BST:

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)  

singleton :: a -> Tree a  
singleton x = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree  
  
treeInsert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a  
treeInsert x EmptyTree = singleton x  
treeInsert x (Node a left right)   
    | x == a = Node x left right  
    | x < a  = Node a (treeInsert x left) right  
    | x > a  = Node a left (treeInsert x right) 

getValue :: Tree -> a
getValue (Node a _ _) = a
```

But I got the following error:

[image: Error message]

Could someone explain how to access the field correctly without using the record syntax *and* what the error message means? Please note that I'm a beginner in Haskell. My purpose is to understand why this particular case throws an error and how to do it it correctly. I'm not asking this to be pointed to more convenient ways of accessing fields (like the record syntax). If someone asked a similar question before: Sorry! I really tried finding an answer here but could not. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you should copy-paste the _text_ of the error.

Comment: for one of them that I am aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add the type parameter to `Tree` in your function's type signature

```
getValue :: Tree -> a
```

should be

```
getValue :: Tree a -> a
```

> Expecting one more argument to `Tree'

means that `Tree` in the type signature is expecting a type argument, but wasn't provided one

> Expected a type, but Tree has a kind `* -> *'

`Tree a` is a type, but `Tree` isn't (?) because it is expecting a type argument.

A `kind` is like a type signature for a type.
A `kind` of `*` means the type constructor does not expect any type of argument.

```
data Tree = EmptyTree | Tree Int Tree Tree
```

has a kind of `*`

It is like the type signature of a no-argument function (technically this is not really called a function, I think)

```
f :: Tree Int
f = Node 0 EmptyTree EmptyTree
```

A `kind` of `* -> *` means the type constructor expects an argument.

Your `Tree` type has a kind of `* -> *`, because it takes one type argument, the `a` on the left hand side of `=`.

A kind of `* -> *` is sort of like a function that takes one argument:

```
f :: Int -> Tree Int
f x = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree
```

Comment: @MoritzWolff I added an attempted explanation of the error :)

Comment: Thanks for providing such a thorough answer to a silly error like this. Accepted.